# PHP date function in Windows and Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, date

Function date that I use:

```
 public function datetime() {
        $today = getdate();
        $datetime =  $today['year'].'-'.$today['mon'].'-'.$today['mday'].' '.
                    ($today['hours']+8).':'.$today['minutes'].':'.$today['seconds'];
        return $datetime;
    }
```

There are two server [ A and B ]
: Server A using Windows,
Server B using Linux

Both server are same for date and time but when I run this php code, the output of time is difference.

Why is that ?

Comment: I have a feeling that your two servers have different time settings (or timezone)

Comment: Have you checked the [`date.timezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) Settings?

Comment: the correct date time is at server A, using Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you only need date do as follow:

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    echo $today;
    ?>
```

If you also need timestamp do as follow

```
<?php 

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        echo $today;
        ?>
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: -1: How would that help? As well as how exactly do you get the timestamp with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`?

Comment: See my edited answer... Sorry I didn't get you  in the beginning

Comment: You need to have a common timezone because the server can be on different region. If you provide common timezone the date you get will be the according to the time zone you provided